# What are the advantages/disadvantages of configuring JS libraries in resource files vs package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs, eslint, package.json

JavaScript libraries like Babel, Nyc, Eslint and many others allows its configurations in resources files or in `package.json`.

For instance, babel can be configured in `.babelrc` file or in a babel entry in the `package.json` file.

What are the advantages / disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the difference when configuring webpack babel-loader vs configuring it within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476373/whats-the-difference-when-configuring-webpack-babel-loader-vs-configuring-it-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pros of `.babelrc`** (or any `.*rc` file):

- Separation of concerns in files
- Easier to find and modify your settings (depending on how stuffed
  your package.json is)
- Some people prefer using a `runcom` file // personal preference

**Pros of `package.json`:**

- Limit file bloat (you could have other `.*rc` files, test config files, task runner files, readmes, etc.)
- "Single source of truth" for app configuration
- Some people prefer using a package.json hack // personal preference

Via - [my_ledge_ends](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4dm4ui/should_i_prefer_using_babelrc_or_configuring_it/)