# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm stuck with the following error when trying to build a react app with Webpack4 and Babel7.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react' from '/Users/me/Desktop/reflask'
- If you want to resolve "react", use "module:react"
- Did you mean "@babel/react"?
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:43:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at items.map (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at passPerPreset (/Users/me/Desktop/reflask/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:58:96)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src main[1]
```

I've tried removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling dependencies with the following.

**Terminal**

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

**Configuration**

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "reflask",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        })
    ]
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './js/components/App.jsx';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in your webpack config did you already try `@babel/preset-react` instead of just `react`?

Btw. you test for `/\.js$/`
Better test for `/\.jsx?$/` (x? means x is optional), because you import a .jsx file in your index.js

Not

```
options: {
    presets: ['react']
}
```

but

```
options: {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
}
```

Answer (score 8):

place .babelrc file at root dir with this inside

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

and remove preset from babel-loader webpack cfg

```
options: {
  presets: ['react']
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the .babelrc file is already in root and includes just what you have above. Also I added presets: ['react'] part because I was getting an error 'Module parse failed: Unexpected token' in ./src/js/components/App.jsx; refering to some html in that file.

Comment: webpack presets option is a replacement for babelrc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476373/whats-the-difference-when-configuring-webpack-babel-loader-vs-configuring-it-wit

Comment: As zebnat says, the webpack presets option is a perfectly fine alternative to babelrc. Anything that helps developers consolidate configuration files shouldn't be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I did it at the end with this settings, (becouse es2015 has been changed https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015)
now!

And presets in **package.json** or **.babelrc** or **babel.config** ::

> ```
> use: {
>                   loader: 'babel-loader',
>                   options: {
>                       presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/preset-env'],
>                           plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
>                   }
>               }
> ```

and..

> ```
> "devDependencies": {
>     "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
>     "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
>     "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.0.0",
>     "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.0.0",
>     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
>     "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
>     "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
>     "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.5",
>     "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
>     "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
>     "babel-node": "^6.5.3",
>     "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-react-pure-class-to-function": "^1.0.1",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.20",
>     "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
>     "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
>     "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
>     "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
>     "webpack": "^4.26.1"
>   }
> ```

and the code that you call to preset example:

```
   "theme:build": "babel theme/src -d theme/dist --presets @babel/react --plugins transform-class-properties --quiet && npm run webpack:store",
```

> presets @babel/react

in github very much forum about the subject!

Comment: Keep having this error with old repo not quite well updated babel dependecies and with setting in webpack 4. The first part did worked for me, having changed my webpack as above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before, I just run the app on another port.

To do so run this command in ur terminal

`npm start`

Then it'll ask if u want to run the app on another port write

`y`

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I had to change ['react'] to ['@babel/preset-react'] in .bablerc 
If your are upgrading babel from 6.x to 7.x

[image]

Comment: It would be more helpful to post the actual code from the file, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If your are upgrading babel from 6.x to 7.x, It worked for me, I had to change  in .bablerc :

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```