# React Native for Android - Using ./gradlew assembleRelease will produce “Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-app' “ error

Tags: android, reactjs, macos, react-native

-1) Follow this official instruction to generate the release APK. 
[a link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

-2) 
Run this command below.

```
    $ cd android
    $ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

-3) 
Result: I receive the following error message.

index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-app'

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-app'

I'm trying to create a release build for Android app using React Native. 
I've searched for potential solution including the below. But I haven't found anything that works for me. 
[Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541561/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js-error-cann)

[package.json] Line 9 to 41

```
"dependencies": {
"mobx": "^5.9.0",
"mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0",
"react-native": "0.58.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.15",
"react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
"react-navigation": "^3.1.2"},

"devDependencies": {
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-jest": "24.0.0",
"jest": "24.0.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
"react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"},

"babel": {
"presets": [
  "react-app"
],


"plugins": [
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    {
      "legacy": true
    }
  ]
]
```

[index.js]

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
```

[app.js]

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, Button, TouchableHighlight, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, StackActions, NavigationActions, withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
```

Expected result: Terminal will finish the process as described in this official guide and produce an apk file under this folder path 
android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

React Native official guide: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Actual output: 
I receive the following error message.

index.js: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-app'

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-app'

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I will answer my own question...
I removed the following line from package.json. 
And I no longer see this error message now.

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    {
      "legacy": true
    }
  ]
]
```