# How can I resolve the following compilation error when running Jest for testing?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs, apollo

Although I am able to start the npm project using `npm start` without any issues with webpack or babel, once I run `npm test`, I find the following error related to testing `App.js` using `App.test.js` (where `App.js` imports `ApolloClient`):

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '__esModule' of object '[object Object]'

| import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
| ^

at node_modules/apollo-boost/lib/bundle.cjs.js:127:74
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/apollo-boost/lib/bundle.cjs.js:127:36)
```

Essentially, I'm confused as to why I get an error when running the test but not when starting the project.

I've tried adding in a number of babel plugins to both `.babelrc` and in my webpack config file:

- @babel/plugin-transform-object-assign
- @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs
- babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs

However, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. My thinking was that this is related to the fact that the file that fails to compile was originally CommonJS.

I was only able to find something relatively similar here, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/6758, but I didn't find a solution.

Is there something that I'm missing specifically related to running tests? I should also mention I've tried frameworks other than Jest and ran into the same issue.

**EDIT:**

I removed everything from `App.test.js` except the imports to isolate the issue so it just contains the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme/build';
import App from './App';
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to resolve the initial error by upgrading `apollo-boost` from version `0.3.1` to `0.4.2`. However, I now have a different error that is similarly frustrating. I am using `Babel 7` and have added the plugin `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` to both my `.babelrc` and to my `webpack.config.js` files. Despite this, I get the following error related to the use of a dynamic import in `App.js` when running the Jest to test `App.test.js`:

```
SyntaxError: Support for the experimental syntax 'dynamicImport' isn't currently enabled

Add @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import (https://git.io/vb4Sv) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable parsing.
```

I'm not sure if there is a parsing error or something else, but I've tried numerous things that have not worked. The closest discussion I could find related to this problem is, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5920, however, the proposed solutions don't work for me.

**UPDATE:**

One thing that I'm trying is to avoid duplication of the `babel` options as right now they're both in `.babelrc` and in the `babel-loader` `options` within `webpack.config.js`. From what I found online ([Whats the difference when configuring webpack babel-loader vs configuring it within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476373/whats-the-difference-when-configuring-webpack-babel-loader-vs-configuring-it-wit/48485578#48485578)), the way to make `webpack` use the settings in `.babelrc` is to not specify `options`. However, doing so results in the same error described above showing up only this time when running `npm start`. I will add that the project that was originally created using `create-react-app`, however, in order to support multiple pages, I needed to customize `webpack`'s configuration and so ejected from it. I'm not sure why this is so convoluted.

Comment: Could you show us the code in `App.test.js`?

Comment: Yes, I just posted it as an edit to the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one of the components in the project's `src` directory had its own local `package.json` file even though it wasn't being used and was not installed as a local dependency in the top level `package.json` (instead imports were done using relative urls). For some reason, the existence of this file changed the behavior of webpack and other tools when starting and testing the project such that none of the top level configurations were used for files within directories with separate `package.json` files. Once I removed these local `package.json` files from the components sub-directory, all the prior issues were resolved. One hallmark of this problem is that compilation errors were not showing up for JavaScript files that weren't nested under an alternate `package.json` file.

Hopefully this is useful for anyone that encounters similar errors as I don't think the cause can be directly determined from the compiler messages alone.

Answer (score 0):

its probably a babel configuration issue, I'm pretty sure jest needs to be compiled to work with create-react-app...
did you specify a setup file in package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
        "/setupTests.js"
    ]
}
```

and in setupTests.js:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: Yes, I have added something like that, and I should mention that at this point I've commented everything except the following from `App.test.js` to isolate the issue even further: `import React from 'react'; import App from './App';`